# Android NDK - Use of APP_STL in Application.mk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, std

I have the latest android ndk installed.  I am using Eclipse along with Sequoyah.

I am trying to use various things that should be found in stlport or gnustl libraries, but I keep getting errors that they cannot be found.

In JNI/Application.mk I only have

```
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

I have tried stlport_static and the gnustl_static/shared and all get the same result.

In my Android.mk I have

```
LIB_TEST_DIR := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(LIB_TEST_DIR)

LOCAL_MODULE := testmod

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libtestmod

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libtest2/

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In a header file that test.cc includes, I have

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iosfwd>
```

But, when I build, it cannot find any of these.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

When I do a clean, I see this:

```
Clean: addiJNI [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_shared [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_static [armeabi]
```

So, it seems like it knew I wanted stlport.  Similar thing happens if I use the gnu libs instead.  But when I build even the simplest example, I get something like...

```
jni/test.cpp:4:19: error: cassert: No such file or directory
jni/test.cpp:6:21: error: algorithm: No such file or directory
jni/test.cpp:7:18: error: iosfwd: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/addiJNI/addiJNI.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse along with Sequoyah.

Comment: Eh, overread that, sorry. Have you added the path to the stlport includes to the C/C++ Options of you project?

Comment: Under Paths and symbols->Languages->GNU C++ there already was this /home/corbin/applications/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/system/include and I added this /home/corbin/applications/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport Does that sound right?  If I look there, I see algorithm etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the problem, not sure why.

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc

It didn't like the .cxx at the beginning.

Comment: LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION must be one word only :)